# How to increase space above & below \tcolorboxenvironment for theorems?

Tags: tcolorbox, theorems, shading, thmtools

The following source uses the `\tcolorboxenvironment{theorem}` environment (from the `tcolorbox` package) to shade the background of the `theorem` environment, where `thmtools` has been used to define the theorem style.

How can the space above and below that environment — so that it is the same as for the `proposition` environment (which uses the same `theoremstyle`)?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\swapnumbers

\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont= \sffamily\bfseries\color{cyan!50!black},
  headpunct={\sffamily\bfseries.},
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  notefont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  headformat=\NAME\NUMBER\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
  bodyfont=\mdseries\slshape,
  spaceabove=12pt,spacebelow=12pt,
  % trying color shading but does nothing ??
  %shaded={bgcolor=mythmback},
]{thmstyle}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{thmstyle}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=chapter]{theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

% For colored boxes
\definecolor{lightcyan}{rgb}{0.88, 1.0, 1.0}
\colorlet{mythmback}{lightcyan!40!white}

\tcolorboxenvironment{theorem}{%
colback=mythmback,coltitle=blue,colframe=mythmback,
left=0pt,right=0pt,
% next 2 keys just change spacing above, below text within_ the frame, not above, below environment
top=0pt,bottom=0pt,}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{The section}
\kant[1]

\begin{theorem}
The square on the hypotenuse of a right triangle equals the sum of the squares of the hypotenuses on the other two sides.
\end{theorem}
\kant[2]

\begin{proposition}
A set is infinite if and only if it has a proper subset that can be put into one-to-one correspondence with the entire set.
\end{proposition}

\kant[3]

\end{document}
```

[image: Insufficient spacing above and below boxed theorem]

**Why did I use `\tcolorboxenvironment` instead of just `\newtcbtheorem`?** Because I need the full power of `thmtools` for various purposes not indicated here.

**What I tried**

- In `\tcolorboxenvironment{theorem}`, to change the last two keys to `top=12pt,bottom=12pt`. However, this just changes the amount of space above and below the text within the box, not the space of the box from the (`kantsum`) text above and below the box.
- Instead of using `tcolorbox`, adding within the `\declaretheoremstyle` the additional key `shaded=bgcolor=mythmback}`, but this seems to have no effect whatsoever.

Comment: You can use for instance `before skip=10pt, after skip=10pt` in the `...` argument of your `\tcolorboxenvironment{theorem}{...}` call.

Comment: @frougon: Perfect, thank you! (Is the "moral" here that any option that can be used for `\tcbset` or `\tcolorbox` can be used for `\tcoloorenvironent`?)

Comment: All options allowed in the optional argument of the `tcolorbox` environment should be fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The space above and below the `tcolorbox` can be controlled with `before skip` and `after skip`, for instance:

```latex
\tcolorboxenvironment{theorem}{
  colback=mythmback,coltitle=blue,colframe=mythmback,
  left=0pt,right=0pt,
  top=0pt,bottom=0pt,
  before skip=10pt, after skip=10pt,
}
```

As far as I know, all options allowed in the optional argument of the `tcolorbox` environment should be fine to use in the second argument of `\tcolorboxenvironment`.

Full code:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\swapnumbers

\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont= \sffamily\bfseries\color{cyan!50!black},
  headpunct={\sffamily\bfseries.},
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  notefont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  headformat=\NAME\NUMBER\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
  bodyfont=\mdseries\slshape,
  spaceabove=12pt,spacebelow=12pt,
  % trying color shading but does nothing ??
  %shaded={bgcolor=mythmback},
]{thmstyle}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{thmstyle}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=chapter]{theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

% For colored boxes
\definecolor{lightcyan}{rgb}{0.88, 1.0, 1.0}
\colorlet{mythmback}{lightcyan!40!white}

\tcolorboxenvironment{theorem}{
  colback=mythmback,coltitle=blue,colframe=mythmback,
  left=0pt,right=0pt,
  top=0pt,bottom=0pt,
  before skip=10pt, after skip=10pt,
}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{The section}
\kant[1]

\begin{theorem}
The square on the hypotenuse of a right triangle equals the sum of the squares of the hypotenuses on the other two sides.
\end{theorem}
\kant[2]

\begin{proposition}
A set is infinite if and only if it has a proper subset that can be put into one-to-one correspondence with the entire set.
\end{proposition}

\kant[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]